# How to display page visits in my web site using data from Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, vs-web-site-project

I have a web site and I want, for every article I publish, to display the number of people who visited that page.

> My idea is to show the number of page visits by fetching this data from my Analytics account.

By following the [tutorial on Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22resource%22%3A%7B%22reportRequests%22%3A%5B%7B%22viewId%22%3A%22193487291%22%2C%22dateRanges%22%3A%5B%7B%22startDate%22%3A%222019-03-01%22%2C%22endDate%22%3A%222019-06-01%22%7D%5D%2C%22metrics%22%3A%5B%7B%22expression%22%3A%22ga%3Apageviews%22%7D%5D%2C%22dimensions%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22ga%3ApagePath%22%7D%5D%2C%22dimensionFilterClauses%22%3A%5B%7B%22filters%22%3A%5B%7B%22operator%22%3A%22EXACT%22%2C%22dimensionName%22%3A%22ga%3ApagePath%22%2C%22expressions%22%3A%5B%22%2Fnote%2F2019%2F05%2F19%2Fr-at-school-r-intro%2Findex.html%22%5D%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D%7D#ReportRequest.FIELDS.view_id) to handle reports, I have created a small chunk of code to retrieve a specific page's visits number:

```
let analytics_api_controller = (function () {
    const API_KEY = "<secret>";
    const CLIENT_ID = "<secret>";

    function authenticate() {
        return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
            .signIn({ scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly" })
            .then(function () { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
                function (err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
    }

    function loadClient() {
        gapi.client.setApiKey(API_KEY);
        return gapi.client.load("https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/analyticsreporting/v4/rest")
            .then(function () { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
                function (err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
    }

    function execute() {
        return gapi.client.analyticsreporting.reports.batchGet({
            "resource": {
                "reportRequests": [{
                    "viewId": "<secret>",
                    "dateRanges": [{
                        "startDate": "2018-03-01",
                        "endDate": "2019-05-01"
                    }],
                    "metrics": [{ "expression": "ga:pageviews" }],
                    "dimensions": [{ "name": "ga:pagePath" }],
                    "dimensionFilterClauses": [{
                        "filters": [{
                            "operator": "EXACT",
                            "dimensionName": "ga:pagePath",
                            "expressions": ["/articles/2019/05/10/myarticle.html"]
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            }
        }).then(function (response) {
            // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
            console.log("Response", response);
        }, function (err) {
            console.error("Execute error", err);
        });
    }

    function _viewsPerPage(pageUrl) {
        return execute();
    }

    // Ctor
    window.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
        gapi.load("client:auth2", function () {
            gapi.auth2.init({ client_id: CLIENT_ID });
        });

        this.window.setTimeout(function() {
            authenticate().then(loadClient);
        }, 2000);
    });

    return {
        viewsPerPage: _viewsPerPage
    };
})();
```

The `setTimeout` is something I added to quickly workaround some timing issues (I need to wait for the API to load, something I will properly solve later).

#### Problem

The code works fine and this is what happens:

1. The page loads.
2. The code kicks in and **I am asked to sign in** to give permission to access my Analytics reports from my Google account.
3. I give consent.
4. In F12 tools I manually run: `analytics_api_controller.viewsPerPage()`, which gives me the report in the console.

> The problem is **point 2**! Every single time I load the page, I am asked to sign in and give permission. This thing is supposed to go in production, so every user will be prompted to access my Analytics info? I assume if they try they'll fail...

- Why am I asked to sign in to use this API?
- Am I using the correct API to solve this issue?

I think I am not really understanding how I am supposed to use the Google Analytics API. What am I doing wrong? How should this objective be addressed?

Answer (score 0):

You used a `Client-side Application` that requires **the users** to login to access your google analytics data. You should use a `Service Application` that allows **your app** to login and access your google analytics data (server-side).

[PHP quickstart for service accounts](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php)